# How to install wxPython on python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pip, wxpython

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6VhA.png)i'm having trouble installing wxpyhton on python 2.7.
I attached the error command togetger.

I tried to install wxPython on python 2.7 by using pip install. But it was not working. So, i tried to find solution to solve this problem. But i couldn't.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please, no screenshots of text! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [Edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last release of wxPython compatible with Python 2.7 is version 4.0. The last release in 4.0 line is [4.0.7.post2](https://pypi.org/project/wxPython/4.0.7.post2/). So install it with the command

```
pip install -U "wxPython==4.0.7.post2"
```

or

```
pip install -U "wxPython < 4.1"
```

(please note double quotes).

Comment: I solved the problem with your solution! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code on cmd:

```
pip install -U wxPython
```

and check your versiyon on python file:

```
import wx
print(wx.__version__)
```

Comment: I've already done that. But it also doesn't work.

Comment: try this code once :  pip install -U wxPython==4.1.1

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution! I feel really grateful